# can a poster paper and poster presentation have different title?

Tags: publications, presentation, titles, poster

I have submitted a poster paper for publication. Now its time to present the poster presentation at the conference.
I am presenting my key idea and results after my work rather than the actual results of what paper intended to explain. I thought this will be fruitful to me. 
To present an idea, the paper title which is used in poster paper is not the best.

> Can I use another title which fits for my presentation?

For example :
Paper title  - Node simulator: Analytics platform for p2p system.
Best fit  title for poster presentation - Behavior measurement for p2p system

Comment: It is not uncommon in my field that the title of the conference paper diverges some from the poster title. Or that the actual poster title is different than the submitted abstract. Things change over the months between abstract submittal, the poster for the conference, and the final paper.

Comment: @JonCuster you suggest me to change the title if it helps to present the poster?

Comment: If the title and the abstract originally submitted are not the best description of the work right now, then, yes, change the title. It should still be recognizable as being the original submission, after several months of evolution though.

Answer (score 3):

The best person to answer is perhaps the meeting organizer.

From someone in biomedical field, I'd recommend against it. If some people read the conference abstracts and decided to see your poster, they would just end up confused. In worse cases they may feel bait and switch, or sloppiness.

Could you use a two-tier title like this?

> **Node simulator: Analytics platform for p2p system**
>
> *Application on behavior measurement*

Comment: This is also a good choice for me. 
Thank you.